# Convert xls to dbf with Libre office using the command line

Tags: command, xls, libreoffice, dbf

Is it possible to convert a **xls** or **csv** file on MSWindows without opening **Calc** (Libre office) from command line.

This is partial solution :

```
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program"

scalc --invisible -convert-to dbf C:\mydata\MATIKGL.xls
```

But the batch file must be in c:\mydata. Is it possible to set the input and output folder in a second line?

### Reference

https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters

Comment: Don't think libreoffice offers conversion functions from the command line. However it is possible to write a utility which will be able to do what you want.

Comment: Could you help me out? write with what, i know my way around vba but  thats all.

Comment: I've found this one but can not make it to work : https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters

Comment: Please add what you have tried to your question. And use a subdirectory to do the conversion, not the root level of the C: drive.

Comment: I think this is actually a question about Windows batch scripting rather than LibreOffice. If I had seen this question six years ago, I might've recommended some of the resources [here](https://ss64.com/links/windows.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 4.n\programs` in the path.

Use the program `soffice` or `scalc`. You can get help with `scalc --help`

Use the option `--convert-to dbf`

See also [Libreoffice convert-to not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062973/libreoffice-convert-to-not-working/22226069#22226069)

Comment: I think I've tried everything. Only thing that works is putting batch file where the xls file is. Beside the fact that batch can not work from other folder (with these lines) :

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program"
scalc --invisible -convert-to dbf C:\X\MATIKGL.xls
also output folder can not be set, tried all combinations. 
Could you please help me with this one? Thanks.