# headless soffice fails silently

Tags: libreoffice, soffice

I can't get headless soffice to tell me why conversion does not work and I cannot seem to figure out what flags I could pass to get some error output.

Version 1:

`/usr/bin/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf test.key --outdir .`

Version with all my silly attempts:

`HOME=/tmp && /usr/bin/soffice --nologo --nofirststartwizard --headless --convert-to pdf test.key --outdir . > logfile.txt 2>&1`

When I run the above I get a silent failure: I execute the command and then there's not console output.

Thoughts?

FYI:
- I'm running this on a Debian server.
- This works perfectly well for PowerPoint conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that not only are you not running an instance of libreoffice on your pc but also that you have not got the libreoffice Quickstarter module running either, both will result in a silent failure, when trying to do this sort of thing.

Comment: FYI - I'm running this on an Debian server.  Also, it works perfectly well for PowerPoint conversion.

Comment: @haberdasher After some digging, it appears that there is an issue opening a keynote file with libreoffice, which is what I am assuming the test.key file is. Export it as a powerpoint (.ppt) file and then use libreoffice to either open or convert it.

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically export from key to ppt?

Comment: I don't believe that keynote as an API. Although I read somewhere that it can be controlled with apple script, so you might investigate that avenue.

Answer (score 1):

Closing other instances of LibreOffice may solve it. It seems to be a bug in LibreOffice.org versions <5.3. You can find an explanation and solutions in 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43907693/1687362).