# lowriter convert-to html crashes with multiple files

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I need to convert multiple `.rtf`-files to `html`. I thought the libre office commandline suit (`lowriter`) would do:

```
lowriter --headless --convert-to html *.rtf
```

But the program finishes (or crashed?) without any error-message at file number 249 (from around 380). I don't know why. As `lowriter` doesn't seem to have a good error-log (acording to the stackoverflow-post from [Arnon Weinberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33137179/5764123)), maybe one of the `.rtf`-files is corrupt and the program crashes. But `lowriter` won't say. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution, but a workaround which workes fine for me:

```
for f in *.rtf; do lowriter --headless --convert-to html $f; done
```

I would be happy to know, if anybody can confirm or explain my problem and come up with a solution!